# Microsoft OLE DB Provider for SQL Server error '80040e14' Incorrect syntax near '='

Tags: sql-server, syntax-error

I get this error when i try to retrieve the data from database using the following piece of code.

Can someone help?

```
set rs = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.recordset")
sql = " SELECT * from COMPANY WHERE COMPANY_ID = " & Request.Form("CompanyId")
rs.Open sql, cnn
```

Comment: Try to debug & check what variable sql returns. You need to do 1)Check how your sql statement looks like and try to run it in your SQL environment. 2)I think there's no issue with your code. You only need to check whether Request.Form("CompanyId") contains any value or is it null or empty.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First of all, this is bad practice to do ad-hoc queries without using parameters.  SQL Injection attack info: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection

To answer the question, though, you need to have single quotes around your varchar or char value that you are searching for.

```
set rs = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.recordset")
sql = " SELECT * from COMPANY WHERE COMPANY_ID = '" & Request.Form("CompanyId") & "'"
rs.Open sql, cnn
```